# Checking for normality distribution error

Tags: r

I want to check for normality in my data but I get an error message when I compute it like that.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
ID System Maneuver value  
1 A E 3
1 A R 2  
1 B E NA  
1 B R NA 
2 A E 3
2 A R 2   
2 B E NA 
2 B R NA 
3 A E 2
3 A R 6  
3 B E NA
3 B R NA
4 A E NA
4 A R NA  
4 B E 5  
4 B R 3 
5 A E NA
5 A R NA   
5 B E 6 
5 B R 6 
6 A E NA
6 A R NA  
6 B E 4
6 B R 5
")

df %>%
  group_by(Maneuver, System) %>%
  shapiro_test(value)
```

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `data`.
x Must group by variables found in `.data`.

- Column `variable` is not found.
  i Input `data` is `map(.data$data, .f, ...)`.

Does somebody know how I can fix that? Is that because of my missing data?

thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the results in a list, you can then use `unnest_wider` to get the output in different columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rstatix)

df %>%
  group_by(Maneuver, System) %>%
  summarise(result = list(shapiro_test(value))) %>%
  tidyr::unnest_wider(result) %>%
  ungroup()

#  Maneuver System variable statistic p.value
#  <chr>    <chr>  <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 E        A      value        0.75    0    
#2 E        B      value        1       1.00 
#3 R        A      value        0.75    0    
#4 R        B      value        0.964   0.637
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `base R` after `split`ting by the groups

```
library(broom)    
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df[c("Maneuver", "System")]), 
     function(x) {
  x1 <- shapiro.test(x$value)
cbind(x[1, c("Maneuver", "System")], 
       statistic = x1$statistic, p.value = x1$p.value) }))

row.names(out) <- NULL
out
#    Maneuver System statistic   p.value
#1        E      A 0.7500000 0.0000000
#2        R      A 0.7500000 0.0000000
#3        E      B 1.0000000 1.0000000
#4        R      B 0.9642857 0.6368868
```